Missing splashscreens when using getLaunchIntentForPackage
I am using getLaunchIntentForPackage to launch other apps from my app.
val launchIntent: Intent? = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(id)
context.startActivity(launchIntent)

Everything works fine, but I am missing the splashscreens. For example, when I launch the Burger King app, I see a white screen at app launch. When I launch it from normal home screen/app icon, I see the splash screen with the Burger King icon.
For the Burger King case, the id is de.burgerking.kingfinder, and the Intent looks like this:
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=de.burgerking.kingfinder cmp=de.burgerking.kingfinder/rbi.android.app.Launcher }

Does anyone know why the splash screens are not shown and how to fix this?
